# A block scoped variable and the activation record

Tags: c, activation-record

I understand that local variables (along with other stuff) are placed in the [activation record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack). And the activation record must exist before the function begins executing. Consider the function below:

```
void f(void)
{
    int i;
    scanf("%d", &i);
    if (i > 10) {
        int j = 22;
        // do some operations on j here.
    }
    // more code below...
}
```

Looking at this function, it seems that the the variable `j` might or might not exist depending entirely on the user's input at runtime. In this case,

1. Will the variable `j` be placed in the activation record?
2. Is this implementation defined (in other words, will some compiler generate code equivalent to `j` being declared outside and above the if` block)?
3. Or, will `j` be simply allocated on the stack segment during execution  if need be? But, in that case how will `j` go out of scope after the `if` block?

I could not find much information regarding this in the C11 spec. Thanks in advance.

Comment: *activation record* itself is implementation defined.

Comment: The language standard doesn't specify *any* of this - these are all implementation details.

Comment: If no more use is made of `j` within the `if` block, the compiler is free to optimize it away entirely. Including the `if` block itself.

Comment: I don't even know what is a `activation record`, never hear of it in my C trip. Hopefully, C is design to hide such detail to the user.

Comment: @Stargateur Haven't heard of this term as well, but a quick search shown that it's just a synonym to a stack frame...

Comment: *"Do not try and access `j`.   Instead only try to realise the Truth... There is no `j`."*  Because when `j` goes out of scope, it ceases to exist.

Comment: _"I could not find much information regarding this in the C11 spec."_ And there's a reason for that... because it's not for C to dictate how it's implemented. If you want to know how your implementation works, just  look at the code it generated.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Ah, of course that would invalidate this question altogether :).

Comment: @AndrewHenle True. Just wanted to know what is happening though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Activation record is also called stack frame, if I am not mistaken. I believe that these are the answers:

Q1. Will the variable j be placed in the activation record?

A1:Yes, unless optimized out by compiler.

Q2. Is this implementation defined (in other words, will some compiler generate code equivalent to j being declared outside and above the if` block)?

A2:It is implementation defined. Depends on the compiler and settings of the compiler, but in most cases, j will be in activation record.

Q3. Or, will j be simply allocated on the stack segment during execution if need be? But, in that case how will j go out of scope after the if block?

A3: No, allocation in C is typically not dependent on the content of the local variable.